# How to highlight todo in a comment line?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'll leave ? at the beginning of a commented line to mark a todo item.
`-- ? TODO ...`
This line will be marked as comment.
How to highlight the ? and the remaining text by Todo color while keep the -- as comment color?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to know what syntax item your filetype uses for comments.

The only languages I know that use `--` as a comment marker are Ada and MySQL. For these, use the following lines, respectively:

```
syntax match Todo /--\s*\zs?.*/ containedin=adaComment
syntax match Todo /--\s*\zs?.*/ containedin=mysqlComment
```

We're matching the entire comment (because we don't want question marks halfway through a comment to be marked as TODO items), but using `\zs` to tell Vim to only start highlighting at the `?`.

Breaking down the regular expression:

- `--\s*`: Match two dashes followed by any amount of whitespace,
- `\zs`: "Start" the match,
- `?`: Match a question mark,
- `.*`: Match anything else that follows on that line.